# Liferay BroadLeaf Integraion

Tags: liferay, broadleaf-commerce

Can some one tell me how to import `broadleaf-commerce` portlet in `liferay` / integration of `broadleaf` with `liferay`. I have a sample of broadleaf portlet as i see the folder structure it looks like maven project.

[image]

I am importing the project as maven project. Is this approach correct..I am newbie to liferay and starting to learn.

[image]

**Project Structure After importing**

[image]

**Error Log After Importing the project**

```
Keystore file 'E:\Software Backups\Coding Zone\liferayworkspace\DemoSite-Portlet-develop\admin\target\admin\WEB-INF\blc-example.keystore' doesn't exist.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- keytool-maven-plugin:1.2:genkey (genkey) @ admin ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.DefaultKeyTool
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.KeyToolCommandLineBuilder was bound.
  while locating org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.DefaultKeyTool

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:546)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.GenkeyMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.KeyToolCommandLineBuilder was bound.
  while locating org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.DefaultKeyTool
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.KeyTool
  while locating org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.GenkeyMojo

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:546)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] ecommerce .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.633 s]
[INFO] core ............................................... SUCCESS [  5.568 s]
[INFO] admin .............................................. FAILURE [  1.691 s]
[INFO] portlet ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.205 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-24T20:33:22+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/208M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2:genkey (genkey) on project admin: Execution genkey of goal org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2:genkey failed: Unable to load the mojo 'genkey' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.KeyToolCommandLineBuilder was bound.
[ERROR] while locating org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.DefaultKeyTool
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] while locating org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.KeyTool
[ERROR] while locating org.codehaus.mojo.keytool.GenkeyMojo
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2:genkey)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR] roleHint: org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:1.2:genkey
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :admin
```

Comment: Are there any particular issues you face post this,as this looks fine!

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal i have updated the question